# "Atomicity" for OnBackStackChangedListener (deep internals of fragment's core)

Tags: android, android-fragments

### Introduction

I am using fragmentManager's API for taking "snapshots" of current "backStack". Also i'm using **OnBackStackChangedListener** to do some logic that depends on these "snapshots" (more about that in the end of question).

Consider case when we replace fragment (C with D):

```
[A,B,C] -> [A,B,D]
```

**OnBackStackChangedListener** will triggers once and taking "snapshot" returns expected result:

```
[A,B,D]
```

Consider another case when we remove all fragments and add another, so called "newRoot" action:

```
[A,B,C] -> [D]
```

Fragment's API has no special method for such action, so firstly, we use **FragmentManager#popBackStack** then **FragmentManager#add**. In this case **OnBackStackChangedListener** will triggers twice.

The problem is that during first call of **OnBackStackChangedListener** "snapshot" has invalid *(invalid for my logic)* state:

```
[] instead of [D]
```

### Possible solution | The Question itself

FragmentTransaction has option **setReorderingAllowed** which does some "optimization magic" and OnBackStackChangedListener triggers only once. Description of **setReorderingAllowed** contains a lot of useful info, but nothing about OnBackStackChangedListener, in other words, there is no documented relation between **setReorderingAllowed** and **OnBackStackChangedListener**.

as summary, working(probably) approach:

```
1) executePendingTransactions
2) My actions
  2.1) popBackStack
  2.2) add (reorderingAllowed true, addToBackStack true)
// Expected: OnBackStackChangedListener called once
```

So main question:

Can someone proof or demystify my approach or suggest another way to guarantee atomicity for OnBackStackChangedListener in mentioned above case? Investigation of source code has no results (process too complex).

P.S. Nested fragments (childFragmentmanager, viewPager and so on) out of the scope of this question

### About "some logic" or What i'm trying to achieve

I'm trying to achieve automanagment(open/close) of DI scopes. (DI aka Dependency Injection)

In short, Fragment's **ViewModel**(aka VM) requests some DI scope, e.g. something like "getOrOpen("scopeKey")". Multiple screens(fragments) can share same scope, for example:

```
[A].getOrOpen("foo") // "foo" RefCount++ // 1
[B].getOrOpen("foo") // "foo" RefCount++ // 2
[C].getOrOpen("bar") // "bar" Refcount++ // 1
```

When fragment gets completely destroyed (corresponding transaction popped from backstack) it's time to try close scope (aka decrement in RefCount), but there is a problem, we cant just decrement counter. Consider example (A replace B):

```
[A] -> [B]
```

Assume both **A** and **B** requires same scope. There is a possible gap for GC to clean our scope (because RefCount == 0), moreover Android doesn't guarantees order of calling A's onDestroy and B's onCreate.

So we should perform cleaning after transaction gets fully completed. **OnBackStackChangedListener** good place to do it. Instead of inc/dec refs from create/destroy we can loop(foreach) backStack, count refs and close unused scopes.

P.S. in my example(architecure) each transaction adds/replaces single fragment, so backStack **[A,B,C]** means that in App opened three Screens: **A, B** and **C**. (Let's ignore DialogFragments for simplicity). Also transaction's tag = fragment's unique Id, so multiple instances of same fragment can request different scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [FragmentManager source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager.java;l=2222?q=executeOpsTogether&ss=androidx), there is only place where `reportBackStackChanged()` (the method that calls all `OnBackStackChangedListener` instances) is called - at the end of the `executeOpsTogether()` method. `executeOpsTogether()`'s responsibility is to execute one or more `FragmentTransaction`s (note that the internal `BackStackRecord` class is what implements `FragmentTransaction`) as a single atomic operation.

That method is only called from one method, [`removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute()`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager.java;l=2056?q=executeOpsTogether&ss=androidx). This method is what looks at each `FragmentTransaction` and checks whether `setReorderingAllowed(true)` has been called (the `mReorderingAllowed` flag).

If all operations have that flag set then this method results in just a single call to `executeOpsTogether()`. This is why you only see a single callback to your `OnBackStackChangedListener` and is exactly why [the Navigation Component always uses `setReorderingAllowed(true)`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130870707).

Therefore as long as you use `setReorderingAllowed(true)`, `commit()`, and `popBackStack()` (i.e., not `commitNow()` or `popBackStackImmediate()` which both execute just that one operation immediately), all enqueued operations are executed as a single atomic operation and result in just a single callback to `OnBackStackChangedListener` with a consistent state in each callback - there would no other pending operations in flight when that listener is called.